# Help me change my jquery code to add additional div

Tags: jquery

I have a slideshow, its only changing photos. I need to add a new div box on top of each photo. At the moment jquery code takes just #slideshow and .active. How to amend it to grab also new div class ".newbox" (.newbox1 for first photo, .newbox2 for second and so on). Each time a different box has to come up on top of different photos. This is my photo slideshow jquery code:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');

    // use this to pull the divs in the order they appear in the markup
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow DIV:first');

    // uncomment below to pull the divs randomly
    // var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
    // var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
    // var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});

</script>
```

My html:

```
div id="slideshow">
   <div class="active">
        <a href="http://www.mylink.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://route/img.jpg" alt="alt" /></a>

    <div class="newbox"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use jquerys [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

The jquery code to wrap

```
$('.inner').wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

Becomes

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case I am assuming it will be

```
$("img"). wrap('<div class="new" />');
```